# Direct link to write an app review in Google Play Store

Tags: android, google-play

I have the following link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.chrome

If I open this link on an Android device, the Google Play Store app gets opened and shows the details of the Google Chrome app.

At iOS, it's possible to ad `?action=write-review` to the link, this will not only open the app in the App Store, this will also present the `Write a review` window of the app, so that you can write a review without the need to click on the `Write review` button before.

Is there something similar for Android?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I know, Android doesn't have a similar option.

However, Android supports reviewing within your application with [in-app reviews](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review).